# OAuth 2 embedded browsers will be blocked

Tags: ios, google-oauth, google-signin

Google recommends to use their GoogleSignIn SDK for signing in users on iOS. [Google has also deprecated support for embedded browsers](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html). This is not an issue for devices running >= iOS 9 which have SFSafariViewController. However, on devices running < iOS 9, SFSafariViewController is not available, and the GoogleSignIn SDK defaults to presenting a webview for OAuth2 sign in, which shows the embedded browser deprecation message.

This happens with the current Sign in sample project in [their repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/ios/signin) as well.

It also appears to be the case that Apple does not like us pushing people out to Safari in order to sign in.

What is the recommended approach for Google OAuth2 Sign in on devices running iOS 8 and lower?

Comment: Essentially the user needs to update their device to iOS 9 or later or live with the deprecation message.  From April it will stop working althogether on iOS 8, so perhaps just target ios 9+ and move on.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for letting me know. It does seem as though Google just wants people to update to iOS 9.

Comment: OAuth flows on iOS 8 in WebView [will not be blocked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42031574/72176) during this deprecation. That said, it's certainly a good idea to update iOS to ensure you always have the latest security patches applied!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's official answer (found near the bottom of [their blogpost](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html)) is that iOS 8 users will not be blocked from signing in via embedded browsers, but they will see a message telling them that they should upgrade their OS.

Comment: This is correct. Key text is "We will start blocking OAuth requests using web-views for all OAuth clients on platforms **where viable alternatives exist**".  As iOS 8 doesn't have a viable alternative to `UIWebView`, it *won't* be blocked – but we may show an interstitial to users recommending they update.  That interstitial (if any) will be completely transparent to you as it would happen in the middle of the OAuth flow.